# How many ways are there for light (electromagnetic radiation) to heat a material?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

While reading about microwaves, it occurred to me that I have no idea how energy from electromagnetic waves gets turned into heat. And how is the heating through microwaves different than the heating through, say visible light?

So I read up on terms like "dielectric effect", "photoelectric effect", "molecular vibration", etc, but found that the exact mechanisms are often vaguely described, or not related to one another.

For example:

- If electromagnetic oscillations excite molecules with dielectric moment, doesn't that mean that visible light also heats material that way? If so, why is it described as some sort of exception present mostly in microwave ovens?
- If I put a 1kw visible light bulb in my oven, it will easily heat up the contents. For visible light, is some heat also generated through the dielectric effect? How much of the generated heat is from this effect, and how much from the "normal heating mechanism" (molecular vibration?).
- Does the photoelectric effect contribute heat at all when I feel the sun's heat on my skin?
- How many fundamentally different heating mechanisms are there to convert light to kinetic energy?
- Are there frequencies of light that will not heat materials, regardless of power?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow only law of conservation of energy.  Light energy may go through a transparent material, hypothetically, without heating material and without any loss. If light energy (regardless of frequency) is not converted as electric energy or light energy or any other energy other  than heat energy, then it should be converted as heat energy; just to obey the law of conservation of energy.